# MVC customErrors with redirect to subdomain error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-errors

I have project with set of subdomain websites (.NET MVC).
e.g.

```
admin.example.com
weather.example.com
test.example.com
error.example.com
```

All this websites have same style and work as one big project, so my idea is to create one place for error pages as subdomain website (error.example.com). I think that in that case I will get one place where I will support my error pages (design, styling and other things).

My question is how to do that using MVC tools and web.config.

P.S.
Also it will be cool to have one place to log exceptions. For now I'm using elmah to log all exception in database.

Comment: Does anyone can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a usual thing, so I have a workaround.
I used Application_Error of Global.asax to track redirect.